# How can a fragment control another fragment?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I set a button in  A_fragment. I want to change a picture(in B_fragment) when the button is pressed, but when I write the following code, the program flashes back after the button is pressed. How can I do to control B_fragment's picture by the button in A_fragment?Thanks in advance!

```java
public class A_Fragment extends Fragment {


  
     public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

       Button btn_confirm=(Button)root.findViewById(R.id.btn_confirm);
        btn_confirm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

        
                ImageView i1 = (ImageView)root.findViewById(R.id.picture123);
                i1.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            }
        });
        return root;
   }
}
```

Here's the logcat of crash

```
2021-10-02 10:44:51.291 7624-7624/com.example.lili_nav E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.lili_nav, PID: 7624
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageView.setVisibility(int)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.lili_nav.ui.right.SettingFragment$1.onClick(SettingFragment.java:91)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6256)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24701)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

Comment: Please add the crash log from logcat to your question so we can help you

Answer (score 0):

Should get the B_fragement's object

```
FragmentManager fm = getActivity.getSupportFragmentManager();
xxxFragment = (xxxFragment)fm.findFragmentByTag("xxx")
```

Then you can control it.